# output php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

include 'index.php';
include '../db.php';
$query_email = "SELECT email FROM email_addresses"; 
$result_query_email = mysqli_query($query_email)
or die(mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array()($result_query_email)) {

//$email_user = $row[10];
$email_user = $row['email'];

$data = date("Y.m.d");
$subject = "Good news";
$message = ("Hello!");

$sentemail = mail($email_user, $subject, $message, 
"From: abc <xyz.com>\nX-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
}
if($sentemail) 
{

    print("Email has been sent successfully.<br>");
}
else
{
  print("There was a problem while sending email.<br>");
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is to select email addresses from the database and to send them an email. what is wrong with my code, i can't get any email, Help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you running this script in your local server?

Comment: Is `$sentemail` true or false?

Comment: are you running it on localhost? if thats the case you need th setup and SMTP

Comment: Have you tried debugging it yourself?  Do either of the `print`s work?  Don't just post code and say "it's broken, fix it".  Try to fix it yourself, tell us what you tried, and we'll help.

Comment: Not directly related, though quite important: PHP's `mysql_*` extension is being deprecated. [Note the red warning box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect). Switch to `PDO` (or `mysqli_*`) ASAP, and learn about [the advantages of prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here

```
while (mysql_fetch_array($result_query_email)
```

you need to assign the return value of `mysql_fetch_array()` to a variable to be able to use it in the `while()` loop as well as the missing closing `)`

for instance

```
while ($emaildata = mysql_fetch_array($result_query_email)) {
{
    $email_user = $emaildata['email'];
 //.....rest of code
```

*also*

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun, see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql-connect). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli); [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**EDIT**

Also it seems like you are trying to use the variable as a associative array you need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` to do that

Comment: @RocketHazmat yep just saw that - fixed

Answer (score 3):

Set up [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to find out that there's a missing `)` in

`while (mysql_fetch_array($result_query_email) {`

Comment: I have my own server, and i have tried with the same code without querying and i am getting the emails. My doubt is on $email_user = $result_query_email['email'];

Comment: Check all the variables with `var_dump()` (this helps you finding logical errors such as wrong values in database) and activate `error_reporting` (this will help you fix your local setup and syntax errors).

Answer (score 0):

Please set correct SMTP server address in your server PHP.ini if you do not provide in sources code.